# Magically special_from_date is set whenever product is updated

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, special-price

I got a weird issue i can't see to find the reason behind it.
When i update product with a `special_price` and the `special_from_date` is NULL (empty) it updates the `special_from_date` to today.. And i can't seem to find why..

Is this a common bug? (i don't think so) but i also can't seem to find the root of the problem.
thanks in advance!

And for a short workaround how can i safely disable special_from_date or just don't let it update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature :-)

The "magic" happens in the observer `Magento\Catalog\Observer\SetSpecialPriceStartDate` which is executed in the event `catalog_product_save_before`and does exactly what you are describing:

```
/**
 * Set the current date to Special Price From attribute if it's empty.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var  $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if ($product->getSpecialPrice() && $product->getSpecialFromDate() === null) {
        $product->setData('special_from_date', $this->localeDate->date()->setTime(0, 0));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

You can disable this observer if you don't want that to happen. Just add the following code into an events.xml file into your module:

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_before">
    <observer name="set_special_price_start_date" disabled="true" />
</event>
```

Comment: Wow thanks! weird, but i couldn't seem to find anything about this online or on the magento docs? Did i look in the wrong place or maybe didn't search the right words?

And maybe i had to look further into the code.. Thank you for this clear answer!